# Remove numbers at the beginning and end of a string

Tags: r, regex, vector, numbers

I've got the following vector:

```
words <- c("5lang","kasverschil2","b2b")
```

I want to remove `"5"` in `"5lang"` and `"2"` in `"kasverschil2"`. But I do NOT want to remove `"2"` in `"b2b"`.

Comment: Note that in the spiffy answers below, you can substitute `\\d` for the (IMO) more readable `[[:digit:]]` (esp for folks just starting out with regexes or those trying to read code written by others).

Comment: @hrbrmstr I agree it is more readable.  Does this come at a loss in speed?

Comment: Prbly a few ms at regex compile-time, but that's it, so I would not call speed a show-stopper :-) Side note: `\\d` and `[[:digit:]]` match all unicode digits where `[0-9]` just matches standard decimal digits, so either is far better than `[0-9]` if operating in diverse environments.

Answer (score 18):

```
 gsub("^\\d+|\\d+$", "", words)    
 #[1] "lang"        "kasverschil" "b2b"
```

Another option would be to use `stringi`

```
 library(stringi)
 stri_replace_all_regex(words, "^\\d+|\\d+$", "")
  #[1] "lang"        "kasverschil" "b2b"
```

Using a variant of the data set provided by the OP here are benchmarks for 3 three main solutions (note that these strings are very short and contrived; results may differ on a larger, real data set):

```
words <- rep(c("5lang","kasverschil2","b2b"), 100000)

library(stringi)
library(microbenchmark)

GSUB <- function() gsub("^\\d+|\\d+$", "", words)
STRINGI <- function() stri_replace_all_regex(words, "^\\d+|\\d+$", "")
GREGEXPR <- function() {
    gregexpr(pattern='(^[0-9]+|[0-9]+$)', text = words) -> mm
    sapply(regmatches(words, mm, invert=TRUE), paste, collapse="") 
}

microbenchmark( 
    GSUB(),
    STRINGI(),
    GREGEXPR(),
    times=100L
)

## Unit: milliseconds
##        expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
##      GSUB()  301.0988  349.9952  396.3647  431.6493  632.7568   100
##   STRINGI()  465.9099  513.1570  569.1972  629.4176  738.4414   100
##  GREGEXPR() 5073.1960 5706.8160 6194.1070 6742.1552 7647.8904   100
```

Comment: @Tyler Rinker Thanks for the benchmark.  I am a bit surprised with `stringi` results here.

Comment: I think it's because it's such a simple regex.  Generally, `stringi` is super speedy but not always.  Also, while `stringi` is speedy another benefit I've really enjoyed is the consitently operating/named functions.  It's not like it's a dog here as these are microseconds.  So if I were including this in a package function I may go with `gsub` but for analysis I'd use the `stringi` approach (of course that's all opinion).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `gsub` which uses regular expressions:

```
gsub("^[0-9]|[0-9]$", "", words)
# [1] "lang"        "kasverschil" "b2b"
```

Explanation:

The pattern `^[0-9]` matches any number at the beginning of a string, while the pattern `[0-9]$` matches any number at the end of the string. by separating these two patterns by `|` you want to match either the first or the second pattern. Then, you replace the matched pattern with an empty string.

Comment: @thothal If you have more one digit in the beginning/end perhaps, you need `[0-9]+|[0-9]+$`

Comment: Sure, thanks for adding this clarification. I just saw that while I was writing you gave basically the same answer ;) But with the added value of the `stringi` library which I did not know yet. +1

Answer (score 1):

Get instances where numbers appear at the beginning or end of a word and match everything else. You need to collapse results because of possible multiple matches:

```
gregexpr(pattern='(^[0-9]+|[0-9]+$)', text = words) -> mm
sapply(regmatches(words, mm, invert=TRUE), paste, collapse="")
```