# How do I remove a specific sign like a comma partially from a data set

Tags: r

I have a data set like this:

```
Quest_main=c("quest2,","quest5,","quest4,","quest12,","quest4,","quest5,quest7")
```

And I would like to remove the comma from for example "quest2," so that it is "quest2", but not from the "quest5,quest7". I think I have to use substr or ifelse, but I am not sure. The final result is this when I call up Quest_main:

```
 "quest2"   "quest5"   "quest4"   "quest12"   "quest4"   "quest5,quest7"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

All you need is

```
gsub(",$","",Quest_main)
```

The `$` signifies the end of a string: for full explanation, see the (long and complicated) `?regexp`, or a [more general introduction to regular expressions](http://www.zytrax.com/tech/web/regex.htm), or search for the tags `[r] [regex]` on Stack Overflow.

If you insist on doing it with `substr()` and `ifelse()`, you can:

```
nc <- nchar(Quest_main)
lastchar <- substr(Quest_main,nc,nc)
ifelse(lastchar==",",substr(Quest_main,1,nc-1),
                     Quest_main)
```

Comment: That is a superfast way of doing it. But is it possible with ifelse and substr?

Comment: Trik23: See my answer for that. But Ben Bolker's answer is much better :)

Comment: @Trik23 - with `substr` you would first need to find where the `,` occurs, which is much less efficient than `gsub`

Comment: @BenBolker
As a beginner in R, I would like to see how different commands function in R. Just personal curiosity and maintaing a learning curve.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative approach (just for general knowledge) using [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
gsub("(,)(?!\\w)", "", Quest_main, perl = TRUE)
## [1] "quest2"        "quest5"        "quest4"        "quest12"       "quest4"        "quest5,quest7"
```

This approach is more general in case you want to delete commas not only from end of the word, but specify other conditions too

---

A more general solution would be using `stringi`s `stri_trim_right` which will work in cases Bens or Jealie solutions will fail, for example when you have many commas at the end of the sentence which you want to get rid of, for example:

```
Quest_main <- c("quest2,,,," ,"quest5,quest7,,,,")
Quest_main
#[1] "quest2,,,,"        "quest5,quest7,,,,"
library(stringi)
stri_trim_right(Quest_main, pattern = "[^,]")
#[1] "quest2"        "quest5,quest7"
```

Comment: but note that `gsub(",+$","",Quest_main)` would work fine for this case. `stringi` is (generally) *faster* but otherwise is just sugar/convenience here. Other `stringi`/`gsub` comparisons: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26359316/r-removing-numbers-at-begin-and-end-of-a-string/26359372#26359372 , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348643/r-regex-with-stringi-icu-why-is-a-considered-a-non-punct-character/26357004#26357004

Answer (score 1):

With `substring` and `ifelse`:

```
ifelse(substring(Quest_main,nchar(Quest_main))==',',substring(Quest_main,1,nchar(Quest_main)-1),Quest_main)
```