# Remove numbers from strings that appears last

Tags: r, regex

Is there a way to remove numbers from the string at appears only at the last. Example

```
df
Col A
asdf sfsfsd54 sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsf654
sfs sfsa5dfgdf sf54 sfsfsgg98
sfs fsdgfdsgd gdfg8
```

Expected output

```
df
Col A                                       ColB
asdf sfsfsd54 sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsf654       asdf sfsfsd54 sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsf
sfs sfsa5dfgdf sf54 sfsfsgg98             sfs sfsa5dfgdf sf54 sfsfsgg
sfs fsdgfdsgd gdfg8                       sfs fsdgfdsgd gdfg
```

Raw data

```
structure(list(ColA = c("asdf sfsfsd54 sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsf654", 
"sfs sfsa5dfgdf sf54 sfsfsgg98", "sfs fsdgfdsgd gdfg8")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/26359316/680068

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done via: `gsub`:

```
x <- c("test123", "test12", "test1")
gsub("[0-9]+$", "", x)
```

**Edit** - using your data:

```
df <- structure(list(ColA = c("asdf sfsfsd54 sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsf654", 
                             "sfs sfsa5dfgdf sf54 sfsfsgg98", "sfs fsdgfdsgd gdfg8")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                           -3L))
df$ColB <- gsub("[0-9]+$", "", df$ColA)
```

---

```
> df
ColA                             ColB
1 asdf sfsfsd54 sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsf654 asdf sfsfsd54 sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsf
2       sfs sfsa5dfgdf sf54 sfsfsgg98      sfs sfsa5dfgdf sf54 sfsfsgg
3                 sfs fsdgfdsgd gdfg8               sfs fsdgfdsgd gdfg
```

Comment: You can simply do: `df$ColB <- gsub("[0-9]+$", "", df$ColA)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach using `str_remove`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
  mutate(ColB = str_remove(ColA, "\\d+$"))
```

```
                                 ColA                             ColB
1 asdf sfsfsd54 sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsf654 asdf sfsfsd54 sdfsdfsdf sdfsdfsf
2       sfs sfsa5dfgdf sf54 sfsfsgg98      sfs sfsa5dfgdf sf54 sfsfsgg
3                 sfs fsdgfdsgd gdfg8               sfs fsdgfdsgd gdfg
```